# OpenCL variables or array in kernel cost memory?

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to run the following code about OpenCL. In kernel function, I will define an array `int arr[1000] = {0};`

```
kernel void test()
{
    int arr[1000] = {0};
}
```

Then I will create `N` threads to run the kernel.

```
cl::CommandQueue cmdQueue;
cmdQueue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(N), cl::NullRange); // kernel here is the one running test()
```

My question is, since we know that OpenCL will parallel run the threads, does it mean that, the peak memory will be `N * 1000 * sizeof(int)`?

Comment: What about stack space?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to OpenCL (yes, that's what I meant :).

The kernel function *operates* on kernel operands passed in from the host (CPU) - so you'd allocate your array on the host using [clCreateBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) and set the arg using [clSetKernelArg](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html). Your kernel does not declare/allocate the device memory, but simply receives it as an `__global` argument. Now when you run the kernel using [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html), the OpenCL implementation will allocate 1000 ints and run a thread on each of those ints.

If, on the other hand you meant to allocate 1000 ints per work-item (device thread), your calculation is right (yes, they cost memory from the local pool) but it probably won't work. OpenCL work-items have access to only local memory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5238064/802203) on how to check this for your device) which is severely limited.

Comment: I think I meant the latter one, i.e. allocate 1000 ints in each thread. Because the array is private variable to each thread, right? So I reckon there will be at most N * 1000 * sizeof(int) memory cost, theoretically.

Comment: It won't be N * 1000 * sizeof(int), it will be M * 1000 * sizeof(int) where M is the local workgroup size, which was left unspecified, so it up to the runtime.

Comment: @Dithermaster Yes, you're technically right. But if you see the OpenCL spec, it's possible that more than one workgroup runs concurrently. This number depends on the memory per workgroup & the implementation. It's also possible that the `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` call fails entirely with `CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES`. I always recommend people compute the memory needed for the overall kernel run instead of relying on specifics of a device/implementation.